# Build fails because a path to a three directory cannot be loaded

Tags: node.js, three.js, rollup

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://ifcjs.github.io/info/docs/Hello%20world/), however my build fails due to this error message:

> [!] Error: Could not load C:\Data\Arbeit\BIM\Ausprobieren\ifcTutorialGithub\node_modules\three\examples\jsm\controls\OrbitControls (imported by app.js): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Data\Arbeit\BIM\Ausprobieren\ifcTutorialGithub\node_modules\three\examples\jsm\controls\OrbitControls'

This file is imported in the first of these lines

```
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
import { IFCLoader } from "web-ifc-three/IFCLoader";
```

Tried to solve it:

- adding .js to the end of both paths throws

> [!] Error: Could not load C:\Data\Arbeit\BIM\Ausprobieren\ifcTutorialGithub\node_modules\three\examples\jsm\utils\BufferGeometryUtils (imported by node_modules\web-ifc-three\IFCLoader.js): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Data\Arbeit\BIM\Ausprobieren\ifcTutorialGithub\node_modules\three\examples\jsm\utils\BufferGeometryUtils'

- adding node_module/ at beginning of the path lets me build but throws this when executing

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: Looks like you're trying to visit your website from the `C:\ ` drive directly. Are you using Rollup like that tutorial suggests with `npm run watch`? Also, Three.js recommends you run a localhost server so all assets load correctly: https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally

Comment: thanks, however I used a localhost with the `npm run build` command.

Comment: I found the solution to this problem on the ifc.js Discord Server (you can find the link [here](https://github.com/IFCjs/hello-world) in the README.md). It seems like the three dependency 0.137.5 caused the problem, using 0.136.0 instead solved it for me.